# phonegap 2.5.0 camera error exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x0) ios

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, memory-management, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap and jquery mobile in my project. I have to capture at least 12 photos on one page I am using the standard code below

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){
            }, { quality : 30, 
                  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
                  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
                  allowEdit : true,
                  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                  targetWidth: 200,
                  targetHeight: 200,
                  saveToPhotoAlbum: false }

        )});
```

But after 3-4 photo capture my application get crash with error exc_bad_access (code=1 address=0x0)

Most of the links at google said its an error because of [the object is no longer exists in memory](https://www.google.com.pk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=exc_bad_access+%28code=1+address=0x0%29&oq=exc_bad_access+%28code=1+address=0x0%29&gs_l=hp.12..35i39l2j0i22i30l2.947.947.0.3614.1.1.0.0.0.0.387.387.3-1.1.0...0.0...1c.2.8.psy-ab.30N_Xdi6uSo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.bmk&fp=6110f42ec8390390&biw=1278&bih=608) I haven't touch the native phonegap code so I am not sure why is it deallocating the object. I tried phonegap 2.2.0 and get into the same problem.